Can I add a composition Block of different adapter types in adapterhub library?
I am using adapterhub library for implementing PEFT methods for fine-tuning. I have a question please:
Can i stack prefix tuning with bottleneck adapter? something like config unioin but as composition block.
Here is my scenario:
Let us suppose I have a trained prefix tuning or lora adapter that i want to load to my model and activate it, and i want to use the output of this adapter as an input to a stacked new bottlneck adapter that will be trained to a different task. So both the loaded lora adapter and the new adapter are activated, but only the new one is trained. Can i do that?
here is my code:
lora_mlm_target = model.load_adapter(f"{config.Config.ADAPTER_SAVE_PATH}/lora-mlm-target",with_head=False)
adapter_name= "adapter_test"

model.add_adapter(adapter_name,config="seq_bn")
model.train_adapter([adapter_name])

model.add_classification_head("mnli", num_labels=3)
model.active_adapters = ac.Stack(lora_mlm_target, adapter_name)


The adapter summery is like i want:

[{'name': 'lora-mlm-target',
'architecture': 'lora',
'active': True,
'#param': 147456,
'train': False,
'%param': 0.22219650503413957},
{'name': 'adapter-test',
'architecture': 'bottleneck',
'active': True,
'#param': 447264,
'train': True,
'%param': 0.6739671334336303},
{'name': 'Full model', '#param': 66362880, '%param': 100.0, 'train': False}]
But when I run evlauate or train it gives me this error:

Invalid adapter setup: str is not a valid adapter name or composition block.

What is the problem? is it not supported in the library ?
